# how to make .eslintrc accept single quotes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslintrc

I am facing this error when I 'npm start' my project:

[image]

I already know the problem is in the .eslintrc file so I added this:

```
"rules": {
    "quotes": [2, "single"],
}
```

and it's not working and it's the only solution I know

Update:

I tried deleting eslintConfig from package.json and it didn't work

and also `"quotes": ["error", "single"]` didn't work

Comment: Is there an `eslintConfig` section in your `package.json`? That's standard for create-react-app, and it can take precedence over your separate `.eslintrc` file.

Comment: @samuei yes there's one in my package.json, should I delete it?

Comment: Is the config meant to be `"quotes": ["error", "single"],` instead of `"quotes": [2, "single"],`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didn't try that solution as some online resources assumed it's wrong

Comment: Yeah, give it a shot.

Comment: @samuei just tried it and it's not working

Comment: Are you trying to allow single quotes or disallow single quotes? Currently, your .eslintrc tells ESLint to allow single quotes and disallow double quotes.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes whenever I allow single quotes, double quotes get disallowed and vice versa so in the end the project never starts because of that error, I just want the error to disappear whichever is the method

Comment: You can just replace all your double quotes in your project with single quotes. Or you can just disable the rule.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes how do we disable it?

Comment: See [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#configuring-rules).

Comment: what react-scripts version are you using?

Comment: You can also configure it through `prettier`.

Comment: 2 and error are the same thing, that wont make any difference. 0 is off, 1 is warn and 2 is error.

Comment: is eslint in your devDependencies? And did you try to disable the rule with 0 and see if it works?

Comment: turning the rule off worked, thanks everyone

Comment: I'm curious why an eslint rule would prevent the script from compiling?

Comment: Yes, I'm also wondering how ESLint is preventing script compilation? It does seem to be the case, but I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to turn the rule off by passing 0 in the `.eslintrc` config file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [0, "single"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the heading the solution is just to add a rule to allow single quotes. Refer below config, checkout rules object:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2020: true,
  },
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
rules: {
  "prettier/prettier": [
    1,
    {
      trailingComma: "es5",
      //to enable single quotes
      singleQuote: true,
      semi: true,
    },
  ],
  ...require("eslint-config-prettier").rules,
  ...require("eslint-config-prettier/@typescript-eslint").rules,
},
};
```

Try this out. If it doesn't work then share a bit more about the problem. May be write a small code try to replicate the issue and then share it here.

I hope this will help you out.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Run eslint with the —fix flag and the problem will go away

Comment: What does that flag do? Does it just ignore errors?

Comment: No it fix’s them, so you no longer get the error message

Comment: I wouldn't do this as it's easy to forget about such a setting and could deceive expectations in the future

Comment: You can see what got fix when you make a pr on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to disable "quote" and "prettier/prettier" rules.

Please you can pass 0 to disable a rule.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "quotes": 0,
        "prettier/prettier": 0
    }
}
```